# Unable to load client print control

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, reporting-services

I have upgraded web application from .NET 2.0 to 4.0. I am using report server sql server 2005 and  report viewer version 8.0. When clicking on the print button of the reportviewer I got a messsage like

> Can not load client print control

. I tried more cases by searching on internet as below.

> 1.Copy content cab file from report server to client c:\windows\system32 folder
>    2.register rsclientprint.dll in registry.
>    3.Install redestribution packages for reportview 2008

One more thing I noticed is that other application in framework 2.0 works fine and printing nicely on the same browser, in that application in Internet Explorer add on loaded shows as rsclient2008.dll. But it's not loaded for my current application. I think that could be the issue. Please suggest any solution.